# Should I use the final modifier when declaring case classes?

Tags: scala, static-analysis, case-class, scala-wartremover

According to [scala-wartremover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) static analysis tool I have to put "final" in front of every case classes I create: error message says "case classes must be final".

According to [scapegoat](https://github.com/sksamuel/scapegoat) (another static analysis tool for Scala) instead I shouldn't (error message: "Redundant final modifier on case class")

Who is right, and why?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It is not redundant in the sense that using it does change things. As one would expect, you cannot extend a final case class, but you can extend a non-final one. 
Why does wartremover suggest that case classes should be final? Well, because extending them isn't really a very good idea. Consider this:

```
scala> case class Foo(v:Int)
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar(v: Int, val x: Int) extends Foo(v)
defined class Bar

scala> new Bar(1, 1) == new Bar(1, 1)
res25: Boolean = true

scala> new Bar(1, 1) == new Bar(1, 2)
res26: Boolean = true
// ????
```

Really? `Bar(1,1)` equals `Bar(1,2)`? This is unexpected. But wait, there is more:

```
scala> new Bar(1,1) == Foo(1)
res27: Boolean = true

scala> class Baz(v: Int) extends Foo(v)
defined class Baz

scala> new Baz(1) == new Bar(1,1)
res29: Boolean = true //???

scala> println (new Bar(1,1))
Foo(1) // ???

scala> new Bar(1,2).copy()
res49: Foo = Foo(1) // ???
```

A copy of `Bar` has type `Foo`? Can this be right?

Surely, we can fix this by overriding the `.equals` (and `.hashCode`, and `.toString`, and `.unapply`, and `.copy`, and also, possibly, `.productIterator`, `.productArity`, `.productElement` etc.) method on `Bar` and `Baz`. But "out of the box", any class that extends a case class would be broken.

This is the reason, you can no longer extend a case class by another case class, it has been forbidden since, I think scala 2.11. Extending a case class by a non-case class is still allowed, but, at least, in wartremover's opinion isn't really a good idea.

Comment: Wow, that indeed sounds like a mess! How comes they didn't prevent also case class to class inheritance, since it presents very similar problems?

Comment: @sscarduzio: it is because of source compatibility. As it was explain to me (https://twitter.com/viktorklang/status/735556776989491201), such a modification would imply a major version increment, which does not seem to be planned by lightbend for now (or for that at least).

Comment: @Dima, I have scala 2.12 but it's still allowing case class to be extended.

Comment: @tintin Yes, you can (still) extends a case class, but _not with another case class_