# How to change the element type of a stream with map in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

I'm a Scala newbie and have a question about Stream.map(). I want a stream of 12 players. Why can not I do that:

```scala
case class Player(number: Int)
Stream.range(1, 12, 1).map[Player](i => new Player(i))
```

What is the right way to use the map function?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the error message says: wrong number of type parameters. You'd have to write something like `.map[Player, Stream[Player]](...)`. But: 1) Those type ascriptions are unnecessary. 2) You don't need `new` to instantiate case classes, a `.map(Player)` would be sufficient. 3) Why do you want `Stream`?

Comment: `Stream.range(1, 12, 1).map(i => Player(i))` - Just let the compiler infer the return type of your _map_. Also, since **Player** is a case class, do not use `new`. Finally, [case classes should be `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561614/should-i-use-the-final-modifier-when-declaring-case-classes/34562046)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The thing is that with Ctrl+click on `map` IntelliJ jumps to `TraversableOnce.scala` but compiler doesn't accept this `map` with single type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The method `map` requires two type arguments (element type *and* the type of returned collection, which might depend in a non-trivial way on the element type). Both arguments are usually omitted.
2. You don't need `new` to instantiate case classes. Indeed, the `Player` companion object `Player` can be used as a function from `Int` to `Player`.

Applying these two hints gives you:

```
Stream.range(1, 12).map(Player)
```

However, it is a bit strange that you are using `Stream` for a tiny collection with a fixed number of elements. A `List` or `Vector` would seem much more appropriate here, so you might even try something like

```
1 to 12 map Player
```

---

If you are wondering why `map` takes *two* type parameters, here are few examples:

```
// return `Iterable` instead of `Stream`
Stream.range(1, 12).map[Player, Iterable[Player]](Player)

// return `Iterable` instead of `Stream` and `Any` instead of `Player`
Stream.range(1, 12).map[Player, Iterable[Any]](Player)
```

This will produce values with the specified return types (e.g. `Iterable[Player]` instead of `Stream[Player]`). Thus, the second type argument can be used to control the return type. Normally, you don't need it, and the appropriate type is returned automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Stream.range(1, 12, 1).map(i => Player(i))
```

or

```
Stream.range(1, 12, 1).map[Player, Stream[Player]](i => Player(i))
```

or

```
(Stream.range(1, 12, 1) : TraversableOnce[Int]).map[Player](i => Player(i))
```