# How to enforce encapsulation of immutable class in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability

I am trying to write immutable code in Dart. Dart wasn't really built with immutability in mind, that's why I need to write a lot of boilerplate in order to achieve immutability. Because of this, I got interested in how a language, like Scala, which was built around the concept of immutability, would solve this.

I am currently using the following class in Dart:

```dart
class Profile{
  List<String> _inSyncBikeIds = []; // private field
  String profileName; // public field

  Profile(this.profileName); // You should not be able to pass a value to _inSyncBikeIds

  void synchronize(String bikeId){
    _inSyncBikeIds.add(bikeId);
  }

  bool isInSync(String bikeId){
    return _inSyncBikeIds.contains(bikeId);
  }

  void reset(){
    _inSyncBikeIds = [];
  }
}
```

The same class in immutable:

```dart
class Profile{
  final List<String> _inSyncBikeIds = []; // private final field
  final String profileName; // public final field

  factory Profile(String profileName) => Profile._(profileName); // You should not be able to pass a value to _inSyncBikeIds

  Profile._(this._inSyncBikeIds, this.profileName); // private contructor

  Profile synchronize(String bikeId){
    return _copyWith(inSyncBikeIds: _inSyncBikeIds.add(bikeId);
  }

  bool isInSync(String bikeId) {
    return _inSyncBikeIds.contains(bikeId);
  }

  Profile reset(){
    return _copyWith(inSyncBikeIds: []);
  }

  Profile copyWith({
    String profileName,
  }) {
    return _copyWith(profileName: profileName)
  }

  Profile _copyWith({
    String profileName,
    List<Id> inSyncBikeIds,
  }) {
    return Profile._(
        profileName: profileName ?? this.profileName,
        inSyncBikeIds: inSyncBikeIds ?? _inSyncBikeIds);
  }
}
```

What I understand from Scala so far, is that for every class a `copy` method is automatically created. In order to be able to change a field using the `copy` method, it needs to be part of the constructor.

I want the field `_inSyncBikeIds` to be `final` (`val` in Scala). In order to change the value of the field `_inSyncBikeIds` I need to create a copy of the object. But in order to use the `copy` method, to change the field, it needs to be part of the constructor of the class, like `class Profile(private val _inSyncBikeIds, val profileName)`. But this would then break encapsulation, because everyone can create an object and initialize `_inSyncBikeIds`. In my case, `_inSyncBikeIds` should always be an empty list after initialization.

Three questions:

- How do I solve this in Scala?
- When I use the `copy` method inside the class, can I change private fields using the copy method?
- Does the `copy` method in Scala copy private fields as well (even when they are not part of the constructor, you can't mutate that private field then of course)?

Comment: It sounds like you're conflating a lot of ideas here. Not every class in Scala gets `copy`; only *case classes* get it for free, and those are specifically for use in cases where you *want* the data to be public and immutable. If you're encapsulating private data, you do *not* want case classes. You'd use a regular `class` and you would either not get `copy` or you'd implement it by hand to do whatever makes sense.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thanks! I understand, so even in Scala I need to write my own copy method in order to achieve true immutability for all classes :(

Comment: you wanted the field to be immutable, and also "initialized to empty". That means it would always be empty (you can't change it because it's immutable), no?

Comment: I want to be able to have a make copy of the object, with a string added to the list. Similar to the  `synchronize` method.

Comment: Can't you have a private constructor in dart? Seems like an obvious solution if it's a thing, no?

Answer (score 0):

Scala comes from a tradition that tends to view immutable data as a license for free sharing (thus public by default etc.).  The interpretation of encapsulation is more that code outside an object not be able to directly mutate data: immutable data regardless of visibility satisfies this.

It's possible to suppress the auto-generated `copy` method for a `case class` by making it `abstract` (nearly always `sealed abstract` with a `private` constructor).  This is commonly used to make the `apply`/`copy` methods return a different type (e.g. something which encodes a validation failure as a value without throwing an exception (as `require` would)), but it can be used for your purpose

```
sealed abstract case class Profile private(private val _inSyncBikeIds: List[String], profileName: String) {
  def addBike(bikeId: String): Profile = Profile.unsafeApply(bikeId :: _inSyncBikeIds, profileName)

  // Might consider using a Set...
  def isInSync(bikeId: String): Boolean = _inSyncBikeIds.contains(bikeId)

  def copy(profileName: String = profileName): Profile = Profile.unsafeApply(_inSyncBikeIds, profileName)
}

object Profile {
  def apply(profileName: String): Profile = unsafeApply(Nil, profileName)
  private[Profile] def apply(_inSyncBikeIds: List[String], profileName: String): Profile = new Profile(_inSyncBikeIds, profileName) {}
}
```

`unsafeApply` is more common for the validation as value use-case, but the main purpose it serves is to limit the concrete implementations of the abstract `Profile` to only that anonymous implementation; this monomorphism has beneficial implications for runtime performance.

Notes: `case class`es are `Serializable`, so there is a Java serialization hole: in application code this is solvable by *never ever using Java serialization because it's broken, but it makes up for being broken by being completely evil* (i.e. if you have a Scala application that uses Java serialization, you should probably re-evaluate the choices that led you there).

There's no way to encode `sealed`ness in JVM bytecode AFAIK (Scala uses an annotation, IIRC, so Scala will limit extension of `Profile` to that compilation unit but, e.g, Kotlin won't), nor is the `private[Profile]` access control encoded in a way that JVM languages which aren't Scala will enforce (the `unsafeApply` method is actually `public` in the bytecode).  Again, in application code, the obvious question is "why are you trying to use this from Java/Kotlin/Clojure/...?".  In a library, you might have to do something hacky like throw an exception, catch it and inspect the top frames of the stack, throwing again if it's not hunky-dory.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it is possible in dart, but in scala this would be done with a private constructor:

```
   class Profile private (val _foo: Seq[String], val bar: String) {
      def this(bar: String) = this(Nil, bar)
    }
```

This lets you define

```
   private copy(foo: Seq[String], bar: String) = new Profile(foo, bar)
```

This is fine *as long the class is `final`*. If you subclass it, badness ensues: `Child.copy()` returns an instance of `Parent`, unless you override `copy` in every subclass, but there is no good way to enforce it (scala 3 admittedly has some improvement over this).

The generated `copy` method you mentioned only works for case classes. But subclassing a case class would lead to some [even more interesting results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561614/should-i-use-the-final-modifier-when-declaring-case-classes/34562046#34562046).

This is *really* rarely useful though. Looking at your code for instance, if I read the ask correctly, you want the user to *not* be able to do
`Profile(List("foo"), "bar")` but  `Profile("bar").synchronize("foo")` is still possible even though it produces *exactly the same* result. This hardly seems useful.